# C# Server And client

Tags: c#, .net, client

**Hello, 
I Had been working on a simple server/client
but there was a problem i couldn't type 2 messages after each others on one cmd (client/server) so i made a timer with the send/receive command but when i start it it stops in the same seconds**

***Here is the Server's Code***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

    namespace Server
    {
        class Program
        {
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            static TcpClient connected;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1980);

                listener.Start();
                connected = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerTick);
                timer.Interval = 100;

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            static byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            static void send()
            {

                NetworkStream stream = connected.GetStream();
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                send();
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            public static void timerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                    receive();

            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            static void sendCP()
            {

                NetworkStream stream = connected.GetStream();
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Connected To Server");
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            }



            static void receive()
            {
                NetworkStream stream = connected.GetStream();
                int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                string rec = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, data);

                Console.WriteLine("Client: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, data));
                for (; ; ) { }
            }
        }
    }
```

***This is the Client's Code***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static TcpClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
          timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerTick);
          timer.Interval = 1000;
          client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1980);
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                sendCP();
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        public static void timerTick(object source,ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                receive();
            }
        }
        static byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        static void send()
        {

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            send();
        }
        static void sendCP()
        {

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Connected To Client");
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        static void receive()
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            string rec = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
            Console.WriteLine("Server: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, data));
        }
    }
}
```

***Hope Anybody Could Help me and Thanks!***

Comment: Can you be more *specific* with your question? we're not going to debug your code...

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting to have application-level messages without designing a protocol that provides them. TCP has no notion of application-level messages -- so if you need them, *you* have to design them and *you* have to code them.

Comment: Isn't there a way to thread the receive Function because it doesn't receive except when its the client/server's turn to receive

Comment: Don't call `receive` unless it's your turn to receive. That's one of the things a protocol would specify -- who sends and who receives and when, how they identify complete messages, and so on. You forgot to design a protocol, so there's no way to implement correctly because you don't know what you're supposed to implement. (What does your `receive` function receive? A message? You have no such thing.)

Comment: You need to specify which side sends and when. You need to specify what an application-level message is and how receivers know when they've received a whole one. Messages should be specified at the byte level. You should also specify how connections are set up and shut down, when connections should be closed, and so on. You should specify in enough detail so that if two pieces of code follow the specification, they will be able to interoperate successfully.

Comment: sorry, but i've never made a protocol , i want to send images,videos and text messages , how can i specify that this is a text , or an image , or a video and how can i convert videos , images to bytes , can you please give me examples, i would be pleased if you do

Comment: What is your code supposed to do exactly? Where does it fail? Try to explain your situation better so others especially those with similar problems can understand.

Comment: Well i need to make the server/client receive and send packets , and i would be pleased if you tell me how do i specify if the received packet was (video-text-images...etc) thanks

Comment: @TarekAdel: Why not use a protocol that already exists for this purpose, such as HTTP? You're talking about re-inventing a mighty big wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the timers but never start them, program quits after start. There are more errors in your code, mixing scheduled operation with event driven. Every 1000 ms tries to send something, but waiting for Console.ReadLine()

Comment: i've made a windows application and worked properly, there is one more thing missing , how can i specify that this is a message or an image or etc....

Comment: In Winforms application you have a loop, which draws the form, handles message loop. In console application you have to program your loop.